# Extending DataList to accept a new InsertCommand from LinkButtons

Tags: c#, insert, datalist, linkbutton, event-handling

I'm trying to subclass DataList to accept a new Command from embedded LinkButtons.  Here's my abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseFieldGroup : DataList
{
    public const string InsertCommandName = "Insert";
    public event DataListCommandEventHandler InsertCommand
    {
        add
        {
            base.Events.AddHandler(EventInsertCommand, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            base.Events.RemoveHandler(EventInsertCommand, value);
        }
    }
    private static readonly object EventInsertCommand;
    static BaseFieldGroup()
    {
        EventInsertCommand = new object();
    }
    protected virtual void OnInsertCommand(DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataListCommandEventHandler handler = (DataListCommandEventHandler)base.Events[EventInsertCommand];
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

it *seems* right, but the Event isn't being caught; I'm not sure why.  However, I also noticed that LinkButton sends the even up with a RaiseBubble, I don't know if that's an issue or not.  Anyone have thoughts?

Oh, this is 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  Found and fixed; I have to override the OnBubbleEvent of the DataList to accomodate (call) the new command.  See below:

```
public abstract class BaseFieldGroup : DataList
{
...
    protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (e is DataListCommandEventArgs)
        {
            DataListCommandEventArgs args = (DataListCommandEventArgs)e;
            this.OnItemCommand(args);
            flag = true;
            switch (args.CommandName)
            {
                case SelectCommandName:
                    this.SelectedIndex = args.Item.ItemIndex;
                    this.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                    return flag;
                case EditCommandName:
                    this.OnEditCommand(args);
                    return flag;
                case DeleteCommandName:
                    this.OnDeleteCommand(args);
                    return flag;
                case UpdateCommandName:
                    this.OnUpdateCommand(args);
                    return flag;
                case CancelCommandName:
                    this.OnCancelCommand(args);
                    return flag; //??
                case InsertCommandName:
                    this.OnInsertCommand(args);
                    return flag;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```